# State being updated before execution in react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, react-hooks

I am working on a form that takes input(which are multiple images and text from the user) using HOC.
Below is my form component.

```
import React from "react";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Alert from "@material-ui/lab/Alert";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";
import { Snackbar, IconButton } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Loading, Snackbars, UIButton, UITextField } from "../UI/index";
import {
  Paper,
  makeStyles,
  Button,
} from "@material-ui/core";

function Gallery(props) {
  let {
    submitHandler,
    selectImages,
    message,
    galleryForm,
    inputChangedHandler,
  } = props;

  return (
    <div>
      <Paper
        elevation={3}
        style={{ padding: "20px" }}
      >
        <form
          onSubmit={submitHandler}
          noValidate
          id="galleryForm"
        >
          <Grid container spacing={3}>
            <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
              <UITextField
                name="imageTitle"
                label="Image Title"
                value={galleryForm.imageTitle.value}
                onChange={(event) => inputChangedHandler(event, "imageTitle")}
                error={galleryForm.imageTitle.invalid}
                helperText={galleryForm.imageTitle.helperText}
              />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <Grid container>
                <Grid>
                  <TextField
                    id="standard-basic"
                    fullWidth
                    label="Select File To Upload"
                    value={message}
                    error={galleryForm.images.invalid}
                    helperText={galleryForm.images.helperText}
                  />
                </Grid>
                <Grid>
                  <input
                    accept=".jpg , .png, .jpeg"
                    className={classes.input}
                    style={{ display: "none" }}
                    id="raised-file"
                    multiple
                    type="file"
                    onChange={selectImages}
                  />
                  <label htmlFor="raised-file">
                    <Button
                      variant="contained"
                      style={{
                        background: "#D3D3D3",
                        color: "black",
                        fontSize: "15px",
                        borderRedius: "4px",
                      }}
                      component="span"
                    >
                      UPLOAD PHOTOS
                    </Button>
                  </label>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Grid className={classes.center}>
              <UIButton
                type="submit"
                variant="contained"
                color="primary"
                size="large"
                className={classes.submit}
              >
                create gallery
              </UIButton>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </form>
      </Paper>
    </div>
  );
}

export default enhancer(Gallery);
```

And below is my HOC (enhancer) that takes Gallery component

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { compose } from "redux";
import Gallery from "./index";
import galleryFiled from "./galleryField";

export let enhancer = compose((Gallery) => ({ ...props }) => {
  const [galleryForm, setGalleryForm] = useState(galleryFiled);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

  const selectImages = (event) => {
    const updatedForm = {
      ...galleryForm,
    };
    console.log("check:", galleryForm);
    for (var i = 0; i < event.target.files.length; i++) {
      if (event.target.files.item(i).name.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png)$/)) {
        updatedForm.images.value.push(event.target.files.item(i));
      }
    }

    setGalleryForm({ ...updatedForm });
    let message = `${updatedForm.images.value.length} valid image(s) selected`;
    console.log(galleryForm);
    setMessage(message);
  };

  const inputChangedHandler = (event, inputIdentifier) => {
    const updatedForm = {
      ...galleryForm,
    };
    console.log(updatedForm);
    updatedForm[inputIdentifier].value = event.target.value;
    updatedForm[inputIdentifier].invalid = false;
    updatedForm[inputIdentifier].helperText = "";
    console.log(updatedForm);
    setGalleryForm({
      ...updatedForm,
    });
    console.log(galleryForm);
  };

  const clearForm = (event) => {
    let allFormKeys = Object.keys(galleryForm);
    let formData = { ...galleryForm };
    allFormKeys.forEach((formKey) => {
      if (formKey == "images") {
        formData[formKey].value = [];
        formData[formKey].invalid = false;
        formData[formKey].helperText = "";
      } else {
        formData[formKey].value = "";
        formData[formKey].invalid = false;
        formData[formKey].helperText = "";
      }
    });
    setMessage("");
    setGalleryForm(formData);
  };

  const submitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("submit", galleryForm);
    let updatedForm = { ...galleryForm };
    console.log("update", updatedForm);
      console.log("final form", galleryForm);
      clearForm();
  };

  return (
    <Gallery
      {...props}
      {...{
        submitHandler,
        selectImages,
        message,
        galleryForm,
        inputChangedHandler,
      }}
    />
  );
});

export default enhancer;
```

So whenever I click on the upload image button first I use a temporary copy of galleryForm then after getting the right files update to the galleryForm using the useState hooks in selectImage button function.

So my issue is, when initially I print a temporary copy of galleryFrom its print updated galleryForm even I am updating my form at the later stage of function.

The same issue I am facing with the submitHandle function, clearForm function update the galleryForm even I am calling function at the last due to which I lost the form data and getting the empty form even after I am printing galleryForm initially.

Answer (score 0):

You are making use of spreadSyntax to clone your galleryForm, however you must note that spread syntax only make a shallow copy of the object. The nested values within the new object still share references and when you try to update the nested value, the get reflected in the original state too

The correct way to update is to clone the value at each nested level like below

```
const selectImages = (event) => {
    console.log("check:", galleryForm);
    const imagesValue = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < event.target.files.length; i++) {
      if (event.target.files.item(i).name.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png)$/)) {
        imagesValue.push(event.target.files.item(i));
      }
    }

    // Update nested state
    setGalleryForm(prevGalleryForm => ({ 
         ...prevGalleryForm, 
         images: {
              ...prevGalleryForm.images, 
              value: prevGalleryForm.images.concat(imagesValue)
         } 
    }));
    let message = `${imagesValue.length} valid image(s) selected`;
    console.log(galleryForm);
    setMessage(message);
  };

  const inputChangedHandler = (event, inputIdentifier) => {
    const updatedForm = {
      ...galleryForm,
      [inputIdentifier]: {
         ...galleryForm[inputIdentifier],
         value: event.target.value,
         invalid: false,
         helperText:"",
      }
    };
    console.log(updatedForm);
    setGalleryForm(updatedForm);
    console.log(galleryForm);
  };

  const clearForm = (event) => {
    let allFormKeys = Object.keys(galleryForm);
    let formData = { ...galleryForm };
    allFormKeys.forEach((formKey) => {
      if (formKey == "images") {
        formData[formKey].value = [];
        formData[formKey].invalid = false;
        formData[formKey].helperText = "";
      } else {
        formData[formKey].value = "";
        formData[formKey].invalid = false;
        formData[formKey].helperText = "";
      }
    });
    setMessage("");
    setGalleryForm(formData);
  };
```

Comment: Thank @Shubham for the fast response as per your change in inputChangeHandler the changed value is not reflecting on text box infect even after changes being made text box remains empty. And even in selectImage function number of files is not reflected immediately like previous change in the new update.

Comment: Have you checked whether UItextField gives event or the updated value and can you show your UITextFieldComponent

Comment: UITextField is working perfectly and yes there is value and event functionality in UITextField. As my above code value is being updated in the text field as we change the data, so there is no issue with UITextField.

Comment: you say inputChangedHandler doesn't work correctly and you use it with UITextField. The only thing I wanted to confirm is what parameters are being passed on to inputChangedHandler. Can you confirm they are what you need because the update logic sure seems correct if you have event with name and value

Comment: Yes, they are working. I am facing an issue that when i console my form its print empty because of clearForm even I am calling it at the end.If i comment the clearForm function i get the proper output as expected same issue is facing in selectImages function .

Comment: Ok, so as I understand, you want your console to print old value when you submit the form and also with selectImages

Comment: old as mean final form and then the form will clear